# Perl: How to match a string that is not in a given string

Tags: regex, perl

I have unsuccessfully tried to followed instructions from some websites to perform the following:

I want to match any " (quote) that is not inside a string beginning/ending with <% %> and changing it to \"

For example:

```
<p class="paragraph"><% print "Hello"; %></p>
```

Should output:

```
<p class=\"paragraph\"><% print "Hello"; %></p>
```

The string may have several tags and several <% %> sections...

My best match was something like:

```
/<%([^%>]+)%>/
```

However it does not seem to work the way I need...

Thank you so much...

Comment: you should NOT be manipulating html/asp/whatever tagged data with regexes. regexes are not designed for such things.

Comment: In Perl, you can pass code as replacement, so you can match the text outside `<% %>` and replace all `"` with `\"`. However, there is the case of escaped `"` inside string, which I don't know how it should be taken care of...